# Describing the codomain of the function that determines prime factors

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am describing the function that takes some natural number (other than 0) and transforms it into its set of prime factors. I am stuck on how I can describe the codomain. At first I did:
$$
P : \mathcal{N} /\{0\} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N})
$$
But this is wrong: $P(4) = \{(2,2)\} \not\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{N}) $

I then read up on powersets of multisets, but I cannot seem to find a notation that  describes the powerset including all possible repetitions of some non-multiset.

What is the notation I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the set that's the codomain of your function has a common name. You could just define $D$ to be the set of finite multisets of the set of prime numbers. Then the fundamental theorem of arithmetic says your function from the nonnegative integers to $D$ is in fact a bijection. The image of $1$ is the empty multiset.

There are contexts in which you want to enlarge $D$ to include all multisets, and allow $\infty$ too. You can think of that as the set of formal products of perhaps infinitely many primes with perhaps infinite exponents. Formal products and "greatest common divisor" and "least common multiple" make sense in that enlarged $D$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that, when you wrote “its set of prime numbers”, what you meant was “its set of prime factors”.

The codomain is $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})$, where $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers. No need to use multisets here; $P(4)$ is simply $\{2\}$.

Comment: So I described the function wrong, I am actually looking for the entire set. So all of the prime numbers which I have to multiply with each other in order to get the original number back. Which means that p(4) = {(2,2)}